# How to replace specific text to component in angular template?

Tags: angular

I got the data from backend

```
{
    success: "true"
    message: "5000 $APPLES sold for 100 $GOLD"
}
```

So, I have an Angular component where I want to show notify like this

```
<div class="notify"> 
{{notify_message}}
</div>
```

*// Displaying text: 5000 $APPLES sold for 100 $GOLD*

But, I want replace `$APPLES` with

```
<app-currency [type]="APPLES" [value]="5000 "></app-currency>
```

and replace `$GOLD` with

```
<app-currency [type]="GOLD" [value]="100"></app-currency>
```

How can I do that?

Desired result:

```
<div class="notify"> 
   <app-currency 
    [type]="APPLES" 
    [value]="5000">
   </app-currency> 
   sold for 
   <app-currency 
   [type]="GOLD" 
   [value]="100">
   </app-currency>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming that text can vary, you’d need to parse that string in a component, determine what the values, strings and ‘currencies’ are then then dynamically inject those app-currency components. It’s very do-able but requires some research.

Comment: So, how i can parse it ?

Comment: Parsing is the simple bit really. Is this string always in the same format / order?  So (amount) (currency) (some string) (amount) (currency)? Or can it differ?

Comment: order can be changed every time, but "(amount) (currency) " order is the same every time

Comment: and also it s can be just a text, without any currencies

Comment: I’d probably split the string in an array, then loop through the array, find numeric value (and parseInt it) and determine the currency, create a helper object for that in the array. You’ll end up with an array that contains everything you need to dynamically build the template with the app-currency components.

Comment: something like this? [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCmAPWBeGByArABlzAJPgIIAKJAMgKIDKMEIANgCYwBmIATjAIx6EDiAeXIARdAChxrAK5hgUAJbgYABwCGHCPAAqSKAAoEyAFx0oHBWADmAShgBvcTGcxQkWBBUMFCFmiNQAHSe3gboGDaSTi7sXPoM8LCWTEgwaNgA3DDJqQA8dF4+8EyBCdZQABZZANTVOYh2ji6u4NAw8AkAtvBgqAWhxQDa9QC6GdHNzgqs+h3w3b2BwBUaRAbYdihbGPjhAGR77V09QcurBtyb2+i7jROTzvfNbvQJpSBW+iFFTMNgKYgALTcEYAGjmCygkQeAF97nD7gB6REtSCMeDvT7fXw2cZw9SaHR6Qx6SJAA) playground

Comment: Right. But the end goal is to have an array that you can loop in the template that looks something like [{type: ‘currency’, value: 5000, currency: ‘apples’}, {type: ‘text’, value: ‘sold for’}, ….. etc etc]

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find the relevant data. I made it generalize so it will search for the number and pick the number and the next word.

```
var r = /\d+\s([$\w]+)/g;
var searched = notify_message.match(r);
const allItems=[];
searched.map((val,index)=> {
   const prepareData = val.replace('$','').split(' ');
   allItems.push(prepareData);
});

console.log(allItems[0][0]); // 5000
console.log(allItems[0][1]); // APPLES
console.log(allItems[1][0]); // 100
console.log(allItems[1][1]); // GOLD
```

After this you can use it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

We first find notifications by splitting the string into pieces. If the first piece is a number and following piece starts with a `$` we know we've found a notification. We then make an `Notification` out of it and push it to an array `[]` of notifications. In template we iterate over notifications and depending on `type` we can change things (e.g like the background) - but they use the same `app-curreny` component consuming data via `@Input()`'s.

app.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  notificationsArr: Notification[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    // mock subscription
    of({
      success: 'true',
      message: '5000 $APPLES sold for 100 $GOLD',
    }).subscribe((response) => {
      if (response?.message) {
        const stringsArr = response.message.split(' ');

        for (let i = 0; i < stringsArr.length - 1; i++) {
          // Check if string piece is Number and next pieace starts with $ then it's a Notification
          if (
            !Number.isNaN(Number(stringsArr[i])) &&
            stringsArr[i + 1].charAt(0) === '$'
          ) {
            let notification: Notification = {
              value: Number(stringsArr[i]),
              type: stringsArr[i + 1].replace('$', '').trim(),
            };
            console.log(notification);
            this.notificationsArr.push(notification);
          }
        }

        console.log(stringsArr);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {}
}

export interface Notification {
  value: number;
  type: string;
}
```

Html:

```html
<div class="notify" *ngIf="notificationsArr.length > 0">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let notification of notificationsArr">
    <app-currency [type]="notification.type" [value]="notification.value">
    </app-currency>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

currency.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-currency',
  template: `<div [ngClass]="{'goldClass' : type === 'GOLD', 'appleClass' : type === 'APPLES'}">app-currency {{type}} {{value}}</div>`,
  styles: [`.goldClass { background-color : gold; } .appleClass { background-color : red; }`]
})
export class CurrenyComponent  {
  @Input() type: string;
  @Input() value: number;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kcyhxv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcurreny.component.ts